# How do you code into an mp3 file?

Tags: mp3

I'm interested in creating a drm type program.  I want to put code into an mp3 file that checks online to see if it is licensed out.  The online aspect is not something I'm concerned with at the moment, but I've looked online for some resource on doing this, but I've found nothing really that useful.  There are people talking about viruses, but I want this to be intentional and not malicious.  Simply when you play the the mp3 it quickly checks online to see if the license is actually allowed to play.  If it is it plays if it isn't it gives an error and says either you need to log on or buy the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is impossible. mp3 files can't contain executable code. They could contain byte data that could represent code, but the mp3 player would need to interpret it as such and execute it instead of trying to play it as music, which no player does. You would have to program your own player to do this, but since there's no way to constrain an mp3 file to only one player (again, because they can't contain code), you'd have to create your own competing standard. Further, there would be nothing preventing someone from converting this mp3 to a normal non-constrained mp3 and sharing it.

From a less technical standpoint, as a user (who despises DRM) it would irk me to no end if an mp3 was checking up on whether I was "allowed" to have it, and even more so if I was required to be online in order to listen to it, to the point that I would just delete it and never buy/download/steal anything in that format again.

(Does this count as an answer? It was too long for a comment.)

Comment: yes that answers it.  I despise DRM as well, but I was instead thinking of doing it as a project, but I'll find something more constructive to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its surely possible but very difficult. Im not very experienced in coding but using discord i was able to turn an mp3 file into a txt file, But the problem is that it becomes strange characters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).